# Search in sql server database by part of names books

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database

I need to search inside my data base which contain a huge amount of books I use some thing like that but I read about the full text search I want to know what is the advantage of using it and if there is any thing better.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE name = 'book name Tuesday'
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE name LIKE '%caution%'
```

I am working with asp.net with sql server db

Comment: Check out [Fulltext Search for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

found a lot of us full links and yes full text search will be better than this way ,and here are some links to understand it :

http://www.developer.com/db/article.php/3446891/Understanding-SQL-Server-Full-Text-Indexing.htm

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx

the problem would be in the performance so if you are using .net then use lucin.net for indexing and it is much better i did not use it yet because i know about it nearly and here are some links :
http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/c69ef65f-e3c6-409e-ab97-168897c74f83/lucenenet-indexing-searching-entry-level-tutorial.aspx

http://ifdefined.com/blog/post/Full-Text-Search-in-ASPNET-using-LuceneNET.aspx